# C simple algorithm .... improper math

Tags: c, algorithm, math

```
int main()
{
int StrFinal = 10;
int DefFinal = 20;
int IntFinal = 40;
int hp = 10;


int eStrength = 30;
int eDefense = 40;
int eIntelligence = 25;
int eHP = 10;

/*
 *    Begin Battle Sequence
 *
 */

printf("Battle Start! \n");



    while(eHP>0||hp>0)
{
    int act;

    printf("Player HP: %d  Enemy HP: %d  \n ", hp, eHP);
    printf("1 - Attack \n 2 - Magic \n Select Your Move:  ");
    scanf("%d",&act);

    switch (act)
    {
        case 1:
            eHP = eHP - StrFinal/eDefense*5;
            printf("You attacked the enemy! \n ");
            break;

        case 2:
            eHP = eHP - IntFinal/eIntelligence*5;
            printf("You Shocked the enemy! \n ");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid Input");

    }

        printf("The enemy attacked you! \n");
        hp = hp - eStrength/DefFinal*5;
        printf(" Enemy HP: %d \n",eHP);
        printf(" Your HP: %d \n", hp);

}

return 0;
}
```

This is a simple code i am writing for the battle sequence of a text game.  The problem i am having is that the output of user and enemy health is not correct.  By the math, The enemy HP when being attacked should be reduced by 1.25.. truncated from 8.75 to 8.  But the output is not effecting the enemy HP.

If i were to choose 2, the output would be `hp = 5` enemy `hp = 5`

I feel as if it is a dumb mistake or something I am overlooking. I just cant seem to find it.  Any help is appreciated

Also: the damage calculation when the enemy attacks also does not seem to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here -

```
StrFinal/eDefense
```

In your case that evaluates to *10/40* which would be *0.25*. Since both variables are integers this value is truncated to **0**.

To ensure that it evaluates in the way you were expecting it to typecast anyone of the variables (or both) to float.

```
(float)StrFinal/eDefense
```

or

```
StrFinal/(float)eDefense
```

You will find that eHP evaluates to 8 as you expected.

Answer (score 3):

All variable are int .. 
You need to use float variables to hold decimal
mainly for hp and ehp

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.  I am new to c and i was misinformed.  I read that this would not be a problem and that c would truncate the float values into int

Comment: @MichaelSciortino , Float value will be truncated to int, if you assign the   float value to int, but you will miss the precision

Comment: Yes i understand this.  For this particular case the precision is not needed and i desire for it to be truncated.

Comment: @MichaelSciortino There's no float value at all - when you do the division it truncates immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
eHP = eHP - StrFinal/eDefense*5 = 10 - 10/40*5 = 10 - 0 * 5 = 10;
```

That is because of implicit conversions. All numbers are of type `int`. And each sub expression is converted accordingly if necessary.

`10/40` results in a float, but is converted to `int`. Thus you are multiplying by `0` and not by `0.25`.

As soon as there is a `float` type the calculation would result in what you expect.

Other cases are similar.

And `include <stdio.h>` by the way, you are using `scanf(...)`.